# RestEasy client spring integration: can not auto follow redirects

Tags: spring, redirect, client, resteasy

Problem: I can not get RestEasy to automatically follow redirects

I'm using the RestEasy client framework 2.3.4 to consume RESTful JSON services. I'm using the  [rest easy client spring integration](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#spring_client_proxy). If I wasn't using spring RestClientProxyFactoryBean to create my services I would set the [auto redirect flag on the client request factory](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/ClientRequestFactory.html#setFollowRedirects%28boolean%29)

I have tried setting the follow redirect on my HTTP client and following the debug I can see this value is overridden to false by Rest Easy.

[Looking at the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/2.3.4.Final/org/jboss/resteasy/client/ProxyFactory.java#ProxyFactory) I need to get access to the [client invoker](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/core/ClientInvoker.html) that the spring proxy factory creates but it doesn't expose this.

This is like a very common task, surely I am missing something? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a custom client executor on the proxybean factory but that also didn't work e.g

```
              @Override   
                    public ClientRequest createRequest(String uriTemplate) {    
                    ClientRequest clientRequest = new ClientRequest(uriTemplate, this); 
                    clientRequest.followRedirects(true);    
                    return clientRequest;   
                    }   

                    @Override   
                    public ClientRequest createRequest(UriBuilder uriBuilder) { 
                    ClientRequest clientRequest = super.createRequest(uriBuilder);  
                    clientRequest.followRedirects(true);    
                    return clientRequest;   
                    }   
                    }
     proxyFactoryBean.setClientExecutor(new FollowRedirectsClientExecutor()); 

In end extending and overriding the Http client (in this case HTTP Component) was needed to make this work e.g. 

public HttpUriRequest followRedirects(HttpUriRequest request) { 

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {  
            logger.debug("Setting allow redirects");    
            }   

            HttpParams p = request.getParams(); 
            HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(p, true);   
            request.setParams(p);   

            return request; 
            }
            }
            ...

@Override   
public <T> T execute(HttpUriRequest request, ResponseHandler<? extends T> responseHandler) throw
s IOException,  
        ClientProtocolException {   ClientProtocolException {   
            request = followRedirects(request); 
        ...
```